# Why is the snakemake command line parameter -c not optional for local execution?

Tags: snakemake

If I run a command

```
snakemake result.txt
```

I get the error

```
Error: cores have to be specified for local execution (use --cores N with N being a number >= 1 or 'all')
```

Why does snakemake not provide a default `-c 1`? That would shorten the length of the command and make it easier for beginners to experiment with it. If I would like to use a different number of threads, I could still specify it, for example `-c all`.

=> What is the reasoning behind not providing a default value?

Comment: I think this is may be better suited for the snakemake folks? I feel like [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/283#issuecomment-608497273) and [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/308#issuecomment-620158083) already covered what you are attempting to address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of Wayne, I found following comment from johanneskoester :

> Let me cite myself:
>
> ```
> People not coming from make frequently didn't anticipate the fact that it uses 1 core by default, wondering why it does not parallelize.
> ```
>
> Hence, we decided to make the specification of cores explicit. I know
> that it causes additional noise for simple cases, but not for the
> majority. There is always the possibility to define your own default
> via a profile.
>
> I think it does not hurt to think about the amount of paralelization
> before starting a workflow.

https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/308#issuecomment-648067486